# Understanding this Clojure code

Tags: concurrency, clojure

I'm very new to Clojure and I've been struggling to implement some concurrent code. I've found this code on the web. There is a warning that it is not a proper way to do concurrency in Clojure, but I want to understand this code anyway.

```
(def *readers* (map #(agent %) '("one" "two" "three")))
(def *writers* (map #(agent %) '("four" "five")))
(def *mutex* (agent :unlocked))
(def *value* 0)

; mutex implementation
(defn lock [state who success-fn fail-fn]
  (send who (if (= state :locked) fail-fn success-fn))
  :locked)

(defn unlock [mutex]
  :unlocked)

; Must be invoked with send-off since this handler blocks
(defn rand-sleep [state next-fn]
  (Thread/sleep (rand-int 5))
  (send *agent* next-fn)
  state)

; Reader functions
(declare try-read)

(defn reader-got-lock [name]
  (println (format "Thread %s says that the value is %d." name *value*))
  (send *mutex* unlock)
  (send-off *agent* rand-sleep try-read)
  name)

(defn reader-did-not-get-lock [name]
  (println (format "Thread %s tried to read the value, but could not." name))
  (send-off *agent* rand-sleep try-read)
  name)

(defn try-read [name]
  (send *mutex* lock *agent* reader-got-lock reader-did-not-get-lock)
  name)

; Writer functions
(declare try-write)

(defn writer-got-lock [name]
  (println (format "Thread %s is taking the lock." name))
  (def *value* (rand-int 10))
  (println (format "Thread %s is changing the value to %d." name *value*))
  (send *mutex* unlock)
  (println (format "Thread %s is relasing the lock." name))
  (send-off *agent* rand-sleep try-write)
  name)

(defn writer-did-not-get-lock [name]
  (println (format "Thread %s tried to write the value, but could not." name))
  (send-off *agent* rand-sleep try-write)
  name)

(defn try-write [name]
  (send *mutex* lock *agent* writer-got-lock writer-did-not-get-lock)
  name)

(dorun (map #(send % try-write) *writers*))
(dorun (map #(send % try-read) *readers*))
```

Specifically I'm stuck at this line:

```
(defn try-write [name]
  (send *mutex* lock *agent* writer-got-lock writer-did-not-get-lock)
  name)
```

It should lock the mutex and call either writer-got-lock or writer-did-not-get-lock depending on the mutexes state. But where is `*agent*` declared, or is it a shortcut to access the current agent? Then how a `state` is passed to the lock, is it `*agent*` in case of the above call or `*agent*` is `who`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*agent*` is a short-cut for the current agent and is implicitly provided by clojure. `*agent*` is passed as `who`. The final call roughly looks like this:

```
(lock @*mutex* *agent* writer-got-lock writer-did-not-get-lock)
```

Comment: And what do such constructions as name at the end of try-write or :locked in lock mean? Does it set the caller agent to this state after executing the function?